# Copying file contents from a .txt file within a docker and pasting it into a file in home directory

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to copy the contents of a txt file from within a docker container and paste that contents to a txt file within my home directory.

This isn't working hence why I am here asking for some assistance, please?

Here I am assigning the name of the first file of a list of assorted files to text_file variable.

> text_file=$ sudo docker exec --workdir /Docker1 docker_1 ls -Sr | head -1

Here I am trying to copy the contents of the variable into a file within my home directory.

> sudo docker exec --workdir /Docker1 docker_1 cp $text_file > file_in_home_dir.txt

Comment: Why do you use the copy command? Instead of `... cp $text_file > file_in_home_dir.txt` use `... cat $text_file > file_in_home_dir.txt`

Comment: The cat command makes more sense, and I have tried to use it, but instead of pasting the contents of the file, it pastes the file name

Comment: Since a Docker container has an isolated filesystem, would it make more sense to run this process directly on your host?  Or, can you bind-mount a host directory into the container, so that you don't need this long-winded `docker cp` path?

Comment: That would be simpler. Unfortunately, I have to do this remotely outside of the docker container to meet specifications.

Comment: I think the issue is where I am using the variable text_file in the cat command, does anyone know of a way to do this?

**sudo docker exec --workdir /Docker1 docker_1 cat $text_file > file_in_home_dir.txt**

Comment: Transform your first command into `text_file=$(sudo docker exec --workdir /Docker1 docker_1 ls -Sr | head -1)`. From my perspective it is not a proper subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command:

> Copy files/folders between a container and the local filesystem

Example:

```
docker cp -L docker_1:/Docker1/somefile.txt ~/file_in_home_dir.txt
```

The `-L` option makes `docker cp` follow symbolic links for the source file.

Or, using using a shell variable:

```
text_file="/Docker1/somefile.txt"
docker cp -L "docker_1:$text_file" ~/file_in_home_dir.txt
```

Using `docker cp` has the advantage over running a command using `docker exec` that you don't have to rely on a particular command such as `cat` being available in the container and doing what you expect.